# OpenMp to Pthreads IR file

Tags: gcc, pthreads, openmp

What are the gcc command line statements to know the pthread calls for openmp directives? I know about the -fdump command line statements for generating IR file in assembly, gimple, rtl, trees. But I am unable to get any pthread dumps for openmp directives.

Answer (score 4):

GCC does not directly convert OpenMP pragmas into Pthreads code. Rather it converts each OpenMP construct into a set of calls to the GNU OpenMP run-time library `libgomp`. You could get the intermediate representation by compiling with `-fdump-tree-all`. Look for a file (or files) with extension `.ompexp`.

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i;
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for(i=0; i<100; i++) {
        printf("asdf\n");
    }
}
```

The corresponding section of the `.ompexp` file that implements the parallel region:

```
<bb 2>:
  __builtin_GOMP_parallel_start (main.omp_fn.0, 0B, 0);
  main.omp_fn.0 (0B);
  __builtin_GOMP_parallel_end ();
```

GCC implements parallel regions via code outlining and in that case `main.omp_fn.0` is the function that contains the body of the parallel region. In the function itself (omitted here for brevity) the `for` worksharing construct is implemented by using some simple mathematical calculations that determine the range of iterations for the corresponding thread.